# Can't get the value inside getFirstInBackground because of the done method.

Tags: android, parse-platform

Please help me. I am stuck with the done method of parse. I am not able to get the value outside of the method. If I toast it inside the done I get the true value.
But, after the done method is executed the value is "". As I understood the reason for this is the async Task. But I could'nt fint a solution for this.
As I said Toast1->"horizontal"  Toast2->"".

```
    String global=null; 
    public void find(final String col, String getv,final String bullet)
          {
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("orient");
            query.whereEqualTo("createdBy",ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
            query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
                public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                               global=object.getString(col); 
                               Toast.makeText(Drawing.this,global,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();     //Toast 1
                    } else {
                               Toast.makeText(Drawing.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                  }
              });
            getv=global;
            Toast.makeText(Drawing.this,getv, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();          //Toast 2
         }
```

Comment: Seems like a problem of String mutation.

Comment: How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
String global=null; 
private static StringBuilder vm =new StringBuilder("");
public void find(final String col, String getv,final String bullet)
{

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(bullet);        
    query.whereEqualTo("createdBy",ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
    query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {

                global=object.getString(col); 
                if (vm.length()!=0)
                    vm.delete(0, vm.length());
                vm.append(global);
               Toast.makeText(Drawing.this,vm.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();     //Toast 1
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(Drawing.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    });
     getv=vm.toString();
     Toast.makeText(Drawing.this,getv, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   //Toast 2
}
```

I found a solution for this with StringBuilder. It saves my data. But, than came up another problem.  Somehow Toast 2 is executed before Toast 1 and therefore I get the results with a delay of one iteration. For example, I enter "Horizontal" it prints "". I enter "Vertical" it prints "Horizontal".
What can be the problem of this delay?

Answer (score 0):

Your second toast is in the main thread, while your first toast is executed in the background and is subjected to network access and hence getting delayed as compared to your second toast.

Try this:

```
String global=null;
Toast toast2;   // Declaring your second toast variable

private static StringBuilder vm =new StringBuilder("");


public void find(final String col, String getv,final String bullet)
{

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(bullet);        
    query.whereEqualTo("createdBy",ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
    query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {

                global=object.getString(col); 
                if (vm.length()!=0)
                    vm.delete(0, vm.length());
                vm.append(global);
               Toast.makeText(Drawing.this,vm.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();     //Toast 1
                toast2.show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(Drawing.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    });
     getv=vm.toString();
     toast2.makeText(Drawing.this,getv, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);   //Toast 2
}
```

Comment: I understand what you say. My problem is not the Toast, but the value that my function "find" retrieve. I need an updated value of getv. I am new to android that's why I put Toast's to see how everything changes. When my program works fine I will remove them. Do you know how to solve this issue? Thank you.